# Webrtc setRemoteDescription don't work for caller

Tags: javascript, webrtc

Part of code looks like this:

```
if (message.type === 'offer') {
    console.log("got offer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message));
    console.log(pc);
    createAnswer();
}
else if (message.type === 'answer') {
    console.log("got answer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message));
    console.log(pc);
}
```

Calee sets remote description successfully, `pc.remoteDescription` is filled. But caller... Receives the same message as callee but after `pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message));` got `pc.remoteDescription` empty and noting happens. Callee ready to receive stream, but caller gets stucked.

Comment: If you put in error handling then you might learn what's wrong. These calls are asynchronous, so you need need to wait for `setRemoteDescription` to finish before reading `pc.remoteDescription`. The methods get queued internally however, so they won't race.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think the issue is because either `setRemoteDescription` is failing, or there is a race condition between that and `createAnswer`, so add it inside success callback and for clarity, add an error callback too...

something like:

```
if (message.type === 'offer') {
    console.log("got offer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message), function(){
        console.log(pc);
        createAnswer();
    }, console.error.bind(console));
}
else if (message.type === 'answer') {
    console.log("got answer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message), console.log.bind(console, 'success'), console.error.bind(console));
}
```

if Promise and ES6 are supported:

```
if (message.type === 'offer') {
    console.log("got offer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message))
      .then(() =>{
        console.log('success...', pc);
        createAnswer();            
      }).catch(e => console.error(e));
}
else if (message.type === 'answer') {
    console.log("got answer");
    console.log(message);
    pc.setRemoteDescription(new SessionDescription(message))
      .then(() => console.log('success...', pc))
      .catch(e => console.error(e));
}
```